# mysql default charset different when invoked by php

Tags: mysql, set, character

As many others, I'm having some problems with mysql charset. As many others, I want everything to be UTF-8, but mysql was installed with latin-1, and no matter how I try/google/experiment with mysql config there is still latin-1 lurking in client settings.

Ok, here is the setup. I have a (non-root) mysql user 'usr' with a password 'pwd'. Whenever I access mysql via terminal (mysql -uusr -p) and then ask him nicely about his charsets, he tell that he is in love with utf8 (as he ought to be):

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client | utf8 |
| character_set_connection | utf8 |
| character_set_database | utf8 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results | utf8 |
| character_set_server | utf8 |
| character_set_system | utf8 |
| character_sets_dir | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, if I use PHP to access mysql (via the very same user):

```
$mysql_link=mysql_connect('localhost','usr','pwd');
$result1=mysql_query("show variables like 'character%'");
$result2=mysql_query("show variables like 'collation%'");
mysql_close($mysql_link)
```

And print_r $result1, $result 2, it magically falls back to latin-1:

```
character_set_client => latin1
character_set_connection => utf8
character_set_database => utf8
character_set_filesystem => binary
character_set_results => latin1
character_set_server => utf8
character_set_system => utf8
character_sets_dir => /usr/share/mysql/charsets/

collation_connection => utf8_unicode_ci
collation_database => utf8_general_ci
collation_server => utf8_unicode_ci
```

This happens regardless whether I invoke php via browser (as php-cgi) or via terminal (as php-cli).

Kinda fix for that is to set charset manually at each connection:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$mysql_link);
```

That works. But I feel like there should be a way to do that via mysql config.

For reference, Mysql config (my.cfg) includes:

```
[client]
default_character_set = utf8

[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

And PHP config (php.ini) includes

```
 default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Thank forward! =)

P.S. I know that mysql_ functions are deprecated and should be replaced with mysqli_ ones. But hopefully that doesn't have anything to do with this exact problem =)

Comment: Perhaps turn on query logging and see if PHP is calling SET NAMES latin1

Answer (score 0):

If you're like most people, you use the root account to get to MySQL. This little snippet from [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-applications.html) might be your smoking gun.

> It is still necessary for applications to configure their connection using SET NAMES or equivalent after they connect, as described previously. You might be tempted to start the server with the --init_connect="SET NAMES 'utf8'" option to cause SET NAMES to be executed automatically for each client that connects. However, this will yield inconsistent results because the init_connect value is not executed for users who have the SUPER privilege.